# MySQL query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, preg-match

I'm self teaching myself to do MySQL and PHP. It is a new world to me, i have a couple of books and i do a lot of research on google before asking here. So I'm stuck with the following problem and I can't find an answer, I have a MySQL database, the database has a specific field called URL.

Part of the URL field looks like this:

```
&path=products&user=Mark24&id=2616
```

currently i have it set up so people can search for items in the database, and that works great. what i want to be able to add to the search feature is search by user. as you can see the user is in the middle of the entire url so i have this:

```
    $query = "select Productid, Productname, url,  from Products where Productid like '%$keyword%' or Productname like '%$keyword%' or url like '%$keyword%' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
```

Now comes the real issue, ^^ this works wonders, people can actually search for the username and it will display exactly what i want. However if people search for the word "products" or "path" which is also in the url they will get over 2000 matches because every single url in my database has the word products and path. Why I want to avoid that? i don't want customers looking up our entire database, I'm also afraid of server overload because with each query a customer gets an image of the product, along with the product name and the link to the product. trying to load over 2000 pictures also slows down or crashes my browser, so i need to fix this somehow, but i'm not sure how to tackle it.

So is there a way to match only the part that says user="blah" for the URL field? do i do this with PHP, preg-match perhaps???

Any information provided is highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: By not sanitizing it looks like, you may be vuln.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$query = "select Productid, Productname, url,  from Products where Productid like '%$keyword%' or Productname like '%$keyword%' or url like '%user=$keyword%' ";
```

Comment: This works Thank you sooooo much, i can't believe the answer was so simple! i think i tried a million variations of this but not this exactly!

Answer (score 2):

Why not make two more columns? One containing the username and containing the id? And then when you do your search, search in those instead.

Comment: because I would need to edit a table with over 2000 fields? create a new column for every item copy and paste into new column username.. also the id show in the url is very different from the productId that already has its own column. The database is constantly growing daily so it would not make sense to do this for every url on the db.

Answer (score 1):

just search for

```
"%&path=products&user=%what you're searching for%"
```

that way you'll get returned only those rows that have 'product' apart from your path=product parameter.  Alternatively, databases like mysql, postgresql and others allow you to  use [regular expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) as well but that's more costly in terms of processing power.

in regular expression form it would look somewhat like this; with php variable in the middle:

```
"... WHERE url REGEXP  '&path=products&user=" . $user . "&id=[0-9]+$'"
```

if you use something like this, then you would need to protect your inputted value against sql injection by escaping it though. You should start to have a look at [pdo](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) for making database fueled applications and use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) with [bound parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) to safeguard yourself. You'd basically would just need to construct your regular expression and pass it as the parameter to bind.

Comment: `or url like '%&path=products&user=%$keyword%' ";` Doesn't return any results.